# Cannot override content-type header when using form fields in Karate 0.9.5

Tags: karate

When using the [0.9.5 release](https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/download/v0.9.5/karate-0.9.5.zip) the `Content-Type` header is always set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` when doing a form field post.

The authorization server I am using only accepts requests with a `Content-Type` header of just `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (if the `; charset=UTF-8` is supplied it will reject the request).

I have attempted to override this with a `configure headers = ...`, and setting the `Content-Type` header before and after providing the form fields, but none of these stop the header value being overridden.

I have copied the [OAuth2 demo](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature) and added various header overrides (as well as trying with both cases...just incase) to replicate the issue:

```
Feature: oauth 2 test using
    http://brentertainment.com/oauth2

    Background:
        * url 'http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin'
        * configure headers = { Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

    Scenario: oauth 2 flow

    * path 'token'
    * header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    * header content-type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    * form field grant_type = 'password'
    * form field client_id = 'demoapp'
    * form field client_secret = 'demopass'
    * form field username = 'demouser'
    * form field password = 'testpass'
    * header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    * header content-type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    * method post
    * status 200

    * def accessToken = response.access_token

    * path 'resource'
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    # * param access_token = accessToken
    * method get
    * status 200
```

The actual authentication request fails (which is besides the point anyway), but that I can still see the outgoing request contains the `; charset=UTF-8` suffix:

```
1 > POST http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/token
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 96
1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
1 > Host: brentertainment.com
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.11 (Java/11.0.7)
grant_type=password&client_id=demoapp&client_secret=demopass&username=demouser&password=testpass
```

Is there any way to force Karate to use the supplied values for the header?